# Best way to handle number dictionary keys in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple typed dictionary:

```
let frecuencies: {[price: number]: number } = {};
```

I need to get the keys, sort them in a numberical way and run through them in a loop taking into acount that the type of the keys is number:

```
let keys = Object.keys(frecuencies);
keys = keys.sort();
```

This obvioulsy doesn't work because Object.keys returns an array of strings. I know I could pass a function to the sort function to sort in a numerical way, but is there any way to keep the keys typing when getting the keys? Something like this:

```
let keys: number[] = Object.keys<number>(frecuencies);
```

Does exist something like that?

Comment: `Object.keys` isn't generic, maybe `Object.keys(frequencies).map(key => +key)`

Comment: You don't need to sort the keys. Numerical object keys (including number strings) are returned in numerically ascending order by default. If you don't want to deal with the number/string conversion at all, you could also use a `Map`.